# icepdf english font dislocation overlap

Tags: icepdf

[image]

`icepdf` PDF to image, appear   english font  dislocation  overlap, look the image

I Used jar version :

```
<artifactId>icepdf.core</artifactId>
version>4.3.4.1</version>

<artifactId>icepdf.viewer</artifactId>
<version>4.3.4</version>
```

I want get result

[image]

help appreciated

Comment: welcome @hui, seems like you forgot the links. Please edit your comment and add them

Comment: tip : You need at least 10 reputation to post images.   http://imgsrc.baidu.com/forum/w%3D580/sign=863849576f63f6241c5d390bb744eb32/d5be0cf431adcbef022ebc68a8af2edda3cc9f66.jpg

Comment: imaege  http://imgsrc.baidu.com/forum/w%3D580/sign=863849576f63f6241c5d390bb744eb32/d5be0cf431adcbef022ebc68a8af2edda3cc9f66.jpg

Comment: are you sure about the images? (add them, review in progress, but seem to be the same, and to be an error message)

Comment: I want get result    http://imgsrc.baidu.com/forum/w%3D580/sign=918f61903e87e9504217f3642039531b/8029e5dde71190ef5149fc8cca1b9d16fcfa60ca.jpg